# Nodal Analysis - Deriving equations at each node

Tags: circuit-analysis

I've recently come across a question where I need to solve using Nodal Analysis:

[image]

I'm a bit confused about the part where the arrow V<sub>1</sub> points in the opposite direction to the voltage source. I've worked on the question and this is what I've come with so far (all in polar form):

I<sub>1</sub> = I<sub>2</sub> + I<sub>3</sub>

I<sub>4</sub> = I<sub>3</sub> + I<sub>5</sub>

I<sub>1</sub> = <sup>(10/_0 - V<sub>1</sub>)</sup> ⁄<sub>2</sub>

I<sub>2</sub> = <sup>(10/_30 - V<sub>1</sub>)</sup> ⁄<sub>j5</sub>

I<sub>3</sub> = <sup>(V<sub>1</sub> - V<sub>2</sub>)</sup> ⁄<sub>(4 + j4)</sub>

I<sub>4</sub> = <sup>(V<sub>2</sub>)</sup> ⁄<sub>(6 - j8)</sub>

I<sub>5</sub> = <sup>(5/_0 - V2)</sup> ⁄<sub>(5)</sub>

And my nodal equations look like this:

At node 1 (Polar Form):

$$ \sqrt{3}*90^\circ = V_1(\frac{3\sqrt{10}}{40}*18.43495^\circ) - V_2(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}*-45^\circ)$$

At node 2 (Polar Form):

$$ 1*0^\circ = -V_1(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}*-45^\circ) + V_2(0.3867*-6.6666599^\circ)$$

Would this be correct? And does the direction of arrow V<sub>1</sub> have any significance?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the arrows. You can declare \$V_1\$ etc. to be wherever you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is completely *ignore* any of the voltage arrows for your analysis. You should be labeling the nodes and have a reference node anyways, which isn't present in that diagram.

For example, here I've removed those arrows, renamed nodes with lowercase letters, and designated a ground node at the bottom. Do all your analysis using `Va`, `Vb`, `Vc`, `Vc`, `Vd`, and `Ve`. Branch currents are assumed to follow the direction of the arrow on the branch (`I1`, `I2`, `I3`, `I4`, and `I5`).

[image]

**edit:**

Apparently, [arrows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention) denote the assumed positive potential as being from arrowhead minus arrowtail, so we can find that:

\begin{align}
V_1 = V_b\\
V_2 = V_c
\end{align}

Comment: Where does it say or imply 'voltage through'? Arrows alongside components denote voltages; that's common practice.

Comment: Interesting, I learned something new today. It's a notation I've never seen or used before. I've exclusively used or seen +/- to denote polarity before (which interestingly the original diagram uses for voltage sources).